# How do I get to where the Echo Gem is leading?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

I have the Echo Gem that I stole from someone's house, and used it to get to an area where the indicator turns red (indicating, I assume, that that is where I need to be) I am on my boat.

Problem is, I can't get to where I need to apparently be. There are rocks everywhere impeding my path, and I can't seem to get around them.

I am in the top middle-ish area of the map - there are icebergs and little brown rocks and I can't figure out how to get through.

How do I get to where I need to go?

Comment: The Echo Gem is supposed to help you find Ryu Kou... do you know where he is?

Comment: Not a clue, but following the Echo Gem leads me to the spot I mention.

Comment: Do you have Himi in your party?

Comment: Yep. I most certainly do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are in the right place. Keep sailing around the rocks and icebergs in your way and eventually you'll find the path up to the Iceberg Outpost.

When to get to the field of icebergs and small rocks, keep going west until you see 2 openings take the opening closes to the Mercury Lighthouse (the second one) then go around to the east, you should eventually see snow-covered building and an wrecked ship (if you took then first opening, you would have probably ended up on the other side of those small rocks).

If you hit Snowdrift Shrine, then you've gone too far.

Once you've entered the Outpost, you'll need to use Search Psynergy to continue... from there things should play out...

Poor Hou Zan...

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cY0cYAJoW6w&feature=player_detailpage#t=397s) will demonstrate, how to get there.